# XPath locate child following sibling

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using `Selenium` for `Python 2.7.10`.

With `XPath`, I would like to locate the link in `a href`, following the sibling to `minimal-list__title` (i.e. I'm looking for the child beneath `minimal-list__value`). Which XPath should I use?

```
<span class="minimal-list__title">ETF Home Page:</span>
<span class="minimal-list__value">
    <a href="http://www.robostoxetfs.com/">ROBO</a>
```

This is the current attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver as driver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def get_link(driver, key):
    key = key + ":"
    try:
        find_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='minimal-list__title' and . = '%s']/following-sibling::span/*[1]::a" % key).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
    else:
        value = re.search(r"(.+)", find_value).group().encode("utf-8")
        return value

website = get_link(driver, "ETF Home Page")
print "Website: %s" % website
```

Note that I am specifically interested in a XPath that gets the link from the child of the following sibling. This is because the function above uses `"ETF Home Page:"` in the web code as an identifier for what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost correct:

```
//span[@class = "minimal-list__title" and . = "ETF Home Page:"]/following-sibling::span/a
```

Note that you don't need to worry about multiple elements matching the locator since you are using `find_element_by_xpath()` and it would give you the first matching element.

Though, if it would makes sense in your case and you know the "ROBO" label beforehand:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("ROBO")
```

---

To get an attribute value, use `get_attribute()`:

```
find_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class = "minimal-list__title" and . = "ETF Home Page:"]/following-sibling::span/a').get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thanks :) This gives me the element text `ROBO`, but I would like to get the url in `href`. Something like `/following-sibling::span/a[@href]`? Produces the same result however.

Answer (score 0):

```
String e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,"minimal-list__value")]/a)).getAttribute("href");
```

`//*[contains(@class,"minimal-list__value")]/a` is the `xpath`, the `getAttribute` will give you the desired result.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: //*[contains(@class,"minimal-list__value")]/a it is the xpath 
the get attribute will give you the desired result.

Comment: The explanation should be in the post.  There is an edit button above and to the left of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the text `ETF Home Page:` to extract the link `http://www.robostoxetfs.com/` from the child node of the following sibling you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `following-sibling`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='ETF Home Page:']//following-sibling::span/a").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `following`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='ETF Home Page:']//following::span/a").get_attribute("href"))
  ```