# Following-sibling in XPath using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, siblings, xpath-1.0

I can't figure it out how to find xpath using following-sibling for those marked in green in the pic. Basically I want to click on the button called "Open" which is on the same row as the text "front".

[image]

Comment: `//strong[text()='front']/following::a[contains(text(),"Open"][1]`    - slightly off what you're asking, this will just pick the first `a` with text `Open` after your `front` without it being a sibling (but might cause error and pick the NEXT open if that line doesn't have one)   - if you can paste the html as text (not an image!) i'll look a bit deeper

Comment: Or just use jaSON's answer! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath locate child following sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835893/xpath-locate-child-following-sibling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//td[strong="front"]/following-sibling::td//a[.="Open"]
```

P.S. As you didn't provide HTML sample as text (do not provide it as picture!!!) I can't see whether there is a text in `<i>...</i>` node

So you also can try

```
//td[strong="front"]/following-sibling::td//a[contains(., "Open")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath:

```
//td[strong="front"]/following-sibling::td//a[contains(text(), "Open")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> //strong/parent::td/following-
> sibling::td/descendant::i/following-sibling::text()
> [contains(.,'Open')]

The above xpath is assuming the level of Open text and i is of same level

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared the element with text as *front* doesn't have any siblings. So you may not be able to use `following-sibling`.

---

### Solution

To click on the button with text as **Open** which is on the same row with the element with text as **front** you you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='front']//following::td[1]//a[@class='btn default ']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* along with the text:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='front']//following::td[1]//a[contains(., 'Open')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```